# Append data to specific lines to a file

Tags: python, list, file

Lets say i have a file called text.txt with the data

```
    Name
    Age
    City
```

And i have a list in python lets call it myList

```
myList = ['Carl','25','Washingtn']
```

How do i append the first item of the list besides the Name in the txt.
I tried doing

```
try = open('text.txt', 'a')
for i in myList:
 myList.write(i)
```

But by doing this, every value of i gets on the last line in the txt file, and i have no idea how to do it so just the index[0] gets on first and so on.
Would appreciate some help here!

Comment: what output do you want? please post on the question

Answer (score 2):

You can do that, if you get each line, you can append whatever you like at the end of it and rewrite it to a file.

```
# We could keep a counter in mind for getting new elem each time.
count = 0 
myList = ['Carl', '25', 'Washington']
with open('text.txt', 'r') as src:
    with open('dest.txt', 'w') as dest:
       for line in src:
           dest.write('%s%s\n' % (myList[count], line.rstrip('\n')))
           count+=1
```

In addition, you should check if the number of line match the number of element in your list, etc. to make it safer.

Answer (score 0):

this code isn't right.

```
try = open('text.txt', 'a')
for i in myList:
 myList.write(i)
```

get items from MyList and write MyList again?
MyList is `list()` not file.

so try this code

```
myList = ['Carl','25','Washingtn']
result = list()

with open(filepath, "r") as f: # read file
    for line, item in zip(f, myList):
        result.append(line.strip() + " " + str(item) + "\n")

with open(filepath, "w") as f: # write
    f.writelines(''.join(result))
```

*'a'* mode will always be at the end of the file.

more information found https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open